# Carbon React having issues with tooltips clipping in tables

Tags: reactjs, overflow, carbon-design-system

So I have a tooltip. This should describe the headers of a [CARBON/REACT-table](https://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/docs/components-datatable-basic--overview)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Popover, PopoverContent } from "@carbon/react";

type TooltipProps = {
  id: number;
  align?: string;
  className?: string;
  children?: any;
  definition: string;
};
export function TableTooltip({
  id,
  align,
  className,
  definition,
  children,
}: TooltipProps) {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  function onKeyDown(event: React.KeyboardEvent) {
    if (isOpen && event.key === "Escape") {
      console.log("escaped");
      event.stopPropagation();
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Popover
      id={"po" + id}
      align={"bottom"}
      className={className}
      dropShadow={false}
      highContrast
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        setOpen(true);
      }}
      open={isOpen}
    >
      <div
        className={"cds--definition-term"}
        aria-controls={`${id}`}
        aria-expanded={isOpen}
        onBlur={() => setOpen(false)}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
      <PopoverContent className={`custom-table-tooltip`} id={id + "tooltip"}>
        {definition}
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  );
}
```

But like you see in the image, it gets clipped.

[image: Problem is here]

I tried appending to <body> or setting zIndex. I tried to follow this [issue-page](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/issues/7565) (which I presume is a similar problem). With no success. I need to avoid using other libraries.

EDIT: [This issue is more descriptive.](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/issues/14139)

Comment: You say you tried `z-index`, but have you tried `z-index` directly on the `<Popover>` element?  It may not work because of the constructor in the carbon module -- But it's worth a shot to try `style={{zIndex:"9999"}}` or `sx={{zIndex:"9999"}}` directly on the `<Popover>` element.

Comment: doesn't work, i tried<Popover> and <PopoverContent> elements

Comment: i was thinking the solution, would be more in the line of attaching the tooltip content to the body, but i am not really able to do that with ReactDOM.createPortal....

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by implementing the library (floating-ui) that they consider using themselves. Not at all happy with the fix, since I didn't want to use external libraries, but it was the quickest fix and the library is pretty easy and straightforward.